# A Problem using Angular + ArcGIS API for JS: No overload matches this call

Tags: angular, typescript, arcgis-js-api

I am using Angular Typescript with ArcGIS API. Once I copied some sample codes from the documents, there are some bugs on it. I pasted the error message and my codes below.

error:

> No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(properties?:
> GraphicProperties): Graphic', gave the following error. Type '{ type:
> string; color: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'SymbolProperties'. Object literal may only specify known properties,
> and 'type' does not exist in type 'SymbolProperties'. Overload 2 of 2,
> '(properties?: GraphicProperties): Graphic', gave the following error.
> Type '{ type: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'SymbolProperties'. Object literal may only specify known properties,
> and 'type' does not exist in type 'SymbolProperties'.ts(2769)
> interfaces.d.ts(5819, 5): The expected type comes from property
> 'symbol' which is declared here on type 'GraphicProperties'
> interfaces.d.ts(5819, 5): The expected type comes from property
> 'symbol' which is declared here on type 'GraphicProperties'

My Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
 

import EsriMap from "@arcgis/core/Map";
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";
import Graphic from "@arcgis/core/Graphic";
import GraphicsLayer from "@arcgis/core/layers/GraphicsLayer";
import Home from "@arcgis/core/widgets/Home";
import Track from "@arcgis/core/widgets/Track";
 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
 

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  map: EsriMap;
  view: MapView;
 

  constructor() { }
 

  ngOnInit() {
 

    // Add Based Map
    const map = new EsriMap({
      basemap: "streets-vector"
    });
 

    // add initial view, position, and zoom
    const view = new MapView({
      map: map,
      container: "viewDiv",
      center: [-79.502938, 43.767854],
      zoom: 12
    });
 

    // adds the home widget to the top left corner of the MapView
    var homeWidget = new Home({
      view: view
    });
    view.ui.add(homeWidget, "top-left");
 

    const track = new Track({
      view: view,
      graphic: new Graphic({
        symbol: {
          type: "simple-marker",    // <-------- error here
          size: "12px",    // <-------- error here
          color: "green",
          outline: {    // <-------- error here
             color: "#efefef",
             width: "1.5px"
          }
        }
      }),
      useHeadingEnabled: false
    });
    view.ui.add(track, "top-left");



    // draw a point on a layer
    const point = { //Create a point
      type: "point",
      longitude: -79.502938,
      latitude: 43.767854
    };
 

    const simpleMarkerSymbol = {
      type: "simple-marker",
      color: [226, 119, 40],  // Orange
      outline: {
        color: [255, 255, 255], // White
        width: 1
      }
    };
 

    const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    map.add(graphicsLayer);
    const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: point,    // <-------- error here
      symbol: simpleMarkerSymbol
    });
    graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);

  }
}
```

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 2):

I solve it the ugly way by writing:

```
   new Graphic({ symbol: this.txtSymbol as any });
```